# Prebid with amp using DFP

Tags: amp-html, prebid.js, prebid

I'm trying to use prebid with amp, but I'm getting the error:

```
f.js:8 Error: Unknown attribute for doubleclick: prebid.
at w (https://3p.ampproject.net/1496245713200/f.js:12:20)
at E (https://3p.ampproject.net/1496245713200/f.js:22:467)
at va (https://3p.ampproject.net/1496245713200/f.js:9:544)
at https://3p.ampproject.net/1496245713200/f.js:184:250
```

I reviewed the code and I'm using the example from http://prebid.org/dev-docs/show-prebid-ads-on-amp-pages.html#amp-content-page , but I can't find the error.

Here's my amp-ad code:

```
<amp-ad width="300" height="250" layout="responsive" type="doubleclick" json='{"prebid":{"requestBidsDuration":2500,"adUnits":[{"code":"/9999999/XXXXXXXXXXX","sizes":[[300,250]],"bids":[{"bidder":"rubicon","params":{"accountId": "99999", "siteId": "99999", "zoneId": "99999", "sizes": "[15,10]"}},{"bidder":"appnexus","params":{"placementId": "99999999"}}]}]}}' data-slot="/9999999/XXXXXXXXXXX"></amp-ad>
```

remote.html and creative is as the example from prebid.

Comment: Could you add a link to the page which is launching the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to edit the code in the remote.html file.

The problem is that the doubleclick tag does not allow to have any user-defined fields, but the prebid settings in the "json" field of your  tag is one.

This issue can be fixed it by modifying the setTargeting function to remove this field:

```
function setTargeting(config, done) {
    config.targeting = getTargeting(config.slot);
    delete config.prebid;
    done(config);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking at this post after March 2018 remote.html is no longer used nor recomended for using prebid with amp